# How to include a license and copyright notice into a website

Tags: apache-2.0, license-notice, website

I have a website and I'm using a library that is licensed under the Apache License 2.0.

Where should I place the notice?

Should I create a file named `Notice` in the root of the website? Or add it as a comment in every webpage?

Comment: Are you distributing the library to Web site visitors (e.g. JavaScript code), or is the Apache-licensed code only on your server (e.g. you are using Apache-licensed programs to produce  your Web site's output)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to create a file named `Notice` in the root/homepage of the website. At least that's what I did after researching the situation. See the top of my homepage http://www.forkosh.com where it says "...and `Terms and Conditions` enumerates your conditions of use". You can then click that `Terms and Conditions` link on my homepage to read all the legal gobbledy-gook on http://www.forkosh.com/terms.html (By the way, feel free to use any of that terms-and-conditions gobbledy-gook you like. At the time I wrote it, in the late 1990's, I did some research trying to establish appropriate terms-and-conditions of use while simultaneously avoiding any possible liabilities myself. And while I'm no lawyer, my father, brother and ex all are, so I know a lot of lawyer-types.)

Answer (score 1):

If people can view the source code of the website, include the entire text of the license with the rest of the library files. Having a comment on every web page would be excessive. Instead, you can link in the footer to a single page that lists the external libraries and their licenses.

As far as I can tell from [ASF Source Header and Copyright Notice Policy](http://www.apache.org/legal/src-headers.html), the NOTICE file is for people developing software for the Apache Software Foundation.

> This document describes how Apache committers and PMC members should handle source file licensing and copyright notices.
>   It does not apply to developers outside the ASF who are applying the Apache License to their work.

I would think it also does not apply to people using a library that is licensed under the Apache License.